# Spring @jmslistener configuration to read the message in parallel(asynchronously)

Tags: java, concurrency, azureservicebus, spring-jms

I'm using Spring's `@JmsListener` to read and process a message from an Azure topic. I may have 1000+ messages in my topic I need to read the messages in parallel not one by one. Incase any exception while processing the message I need to push the message to Deadletter queue.

Here's the sample code I tried based on Spring Documentation:

```java
@Component
public class Receiver {

  @JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
  public void receiveMessage(Email email) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + email + ">");
  }

}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Application {

  @Bean
  public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                          DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
    return factory;
  }

  @Bean // Serialize message content to json using TextMessage
  public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
    MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
    converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
    return converter;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Launch the application
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);

    // Send a message with a POJO - the template reuse the message converter
    System.out.println("Sending an email message.");
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend("mailbox", new Email("info@example.com", "Hello"));
  }
}
```

I tried by setting the concurrency, but I had no luck.

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory", concurrency = "100")
public void receiveMessage(Email email) {
  System.out.println("Received <" + email + ">");
}
```

Any one can you please advise on this?

Comment: You are only sending one record; what are you expecting?

Comment: @GaryRussell - yes for workout I tried inserting  only one record. Scenario is I'm having 100 messages in my azure topic, I need to fetch all the messages parallelly using JMSListener and process them. If I have any exception while processing the  message I need to push the same to Deadletter queue.   Any best practices and suggestion would be really helpful

Comment: `>I tried by setting the concurrency, but I had no luck.` What do you mean by "no luck" - if you are only sending one record, you won't see any concurrency.

Comment: `>Scenario is I'm having 100 messages in my azure topic,` - I am not familiar with azure, but you might be impacted by a prefetch configuration, which causes all those messages to go to one consumer. Look for such a property and, if present, reduce it to see if it helps. For example, ActiveMQ has a default prefetch of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the prefetch policy like below for batch receive. You can read this nice blog post [Messaging With Spring Boot and Azure Service Bus](https://dzone.com/articles/messaging-with-spring-boot-and-azure-service-bus-1) for details.

(Below code snippet is in Kotlin syntax)

```kotlin
@Bean
@Primary
fun myFactory(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): JmsListenerContainerFactory<DefaultMessageListenerContainer> {
    ((connectionFactory as CachingConnectionFactory).targetConnectionFactory as JmsConnectionFactory)
        .prefetchPolicy = prefetchPolicy()
    val listenerContainerFactory = DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory()
    listenerContainerFactory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
    listenerContainerFactory.setSubscriptionDurable(true)
    listenerContainerFactory.setSessionTransacted(true)
    listenerContainerFactory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE)
    return listenerContainerFactory
}
    
private fun prefetchPolicy(): JmsPrefetchPolicy {
    val prefetchPolicy = JmsDefaultPrefetchPolicy()
    prefetchPolicy.setAll(100) // example 100
    return prefetchPolicy
}
```

Comment: I do not understand Kotlin very well. Can you explain the like - ((connectionFactory as CachingConnectionFactory).targetConnectionFactory as JmsConnectionFactory)
        .prefetchPolicy = prefetchPolicy()

Comment: I tried the equivalent in Java - ((JmsConnectionFactory) (((CachingConnectionFactory) connectionFactory).getTargetConnectionFactory()))
    .setPrefetchPolicy(prefetchPolicy()); . Is this correct? This gives an error - java.lang.ClassCastException: com.azure.spring.autoconfigure.jms.SpringServiceBusJmsConnectionFactory cannot be cast to org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug this, as a first step, I would suggest you to turn on DEBUG logging for org.springframework.jms and see the behaviour and post the log.